# Zimbra 10 ClassNotFound exception

Tags: java, zimbra

After installing last patch on zimbra 10 FOSS i'm getting warn on every zmprov request:

```
2023-11-28 19:52:40,943 [main] WARN : loadCallback caught exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zimbra.cs.account.callback.EventLoggerCallback
        at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375) ~[?:?]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.AttributeManager.loadCallback(AttributeManager.java:1307) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.AttributeManager.loadAttrs(AttributeManager.java:432) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.AttributeManager.<init>(AttributeManager.java:300) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) [?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) [?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) [?:?]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.AttributeManager.getInstance(AttributeManager.java:188) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.Entry.setAttributeManager(Entry.java:140) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.Entry.<init>(Entry.java:117) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.NamedEntry.<init>(NamedEntry.java:43) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.ZAttrServer.<init>(ZAttrServer.java:44) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.Server.<init>(Server.java:38) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.soap.SoapServer.<init>(SoapServer.java:40) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.soap.SoapProvisioning.getAllServers(SoapProvisioning.java:1518) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.ProvUtil.doGetAllServers(ProvUtil.java:3076) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.ProvUtil.execute(ProvUtil.java:1230) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.ProvUtil.interactive(ProvUtil.java:3913) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
        at com.zimbra.cs.account.ProvUtil.main(ProvUtil.java:4163) [zimbrastore.jar:10.0.5_GA_4574]
```

How I can get rid of this?

Comment: Find the JAR containing com.zimbra.cs.account.callback.EventLoggerCallback and add it to your CLASSPATH.  The JVM class loader cannot find it.

Comment: thanks alot but... how can i so this?

Comment: Step 1: Find the JAR that has the missing class.  I found Zimbra JARs at Maven Central.  They look rather old - 2011.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zimbra

Comment: Step 2: Add that JAR to your Maven or Gradle dependencies.  If you aren't using Maven or Gradle, you have to download the JAR with your class and add it to your CLASSPATH or application package.